# symbolic links of libblas.so.3

Tags: linux, symlink, blas

I messed up the symbolic links of my libblas.so.3

I get the error message:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list libblas.so.3
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

When I do:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Nov 23 15:15 /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3 -> /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
```

Then, again:

```
ls -l /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Nov 25 14:36 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3 -> /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3
```

Any help to get ot of this situation would be very much appreciated. I do not know if it is enough information. If not, let me know and I try to provide more. Thanks.

I guess the problem is that /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3 links back to etc/.., however it should point to the actual file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the link in the alternatives directory:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
```

Then, I recreated the link, but pointnig to a real library file. For that I chose the corresponding one from the atlas package:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/atlas/atlas-base/libblas.so.3 /etc/alternatives/libblas.so.3
```